# how to change longblob to image in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get data from a table inside MySQL then put it inside an html table. Almost all the data appears right, but the images that i stored in long blob bugs and appears codified as a lot of characters instead. Everything else in functional as intended. Inside the code foto=longblob image.

```
<?php
      $tipo =$_GET["tipo"];
      $conexao = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","db_tcc") or die ("Não foi possível se conectar com o servidor.");





        switch($tipo){
            case "0":
                    $varsql = "SELECT * FROM tb_locaissp ORDER BY id ASC";
                    break;

            case "1": case "2": case "3":
                    $varsql = "SELECT * FROM tb_locaissp WHERE TIPO='$tipo' ORDER BY id ASC";
                    break;
    }


          $carregar_guias = mysqli_query($conexao, $varsql);

      while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($carregar_guias))
      {
        $id = $linha["ID"];
        $img = $linha["FOTO"];
        $nome = $linha["NOME"];
        $desc = $linha["DESCRICAO"];




        echo "<div class='loc'>
        <table class='tablel'>
        <tr><td class='nome'>$nome</td>  <td><img class='contador' src='like' '> </td></tr>
        <tr><td class='imglo'><img src='$img'></td></tr>
        <tr><td class='desc'>$desc</td></tr>
        </table></div>";
        echo "<br><br>";

      }
    ?>
```

Comment: dont store images in the db, just store the path to the location in the file system

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $img ).'"/>` instead of `<img src='$img'>`

```
echo "<div class='loc'>
<table class='tablel'>
<tr><td class='nome'>$nome</td>  <td><img class='contador' src='like' '> </td></tr>
<tr><td class='imglo'><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $img ).'"/></td></tr>
<tr><td class='desc'>$desc</td></tr>
</table></div>";
echo "<br><br>";
```

Comment: i needed to put another code to complement but it worked, now my problem is that somehow i cant put a class in the <img> or it stops working.

Comment: If you want to mange the image thru css you can have .imglo img {}. Or you can send the code that make you the problem to see what is it. Maybe its only typo?

Comment: yeah was a typo ta got me consused with the ' and " thanks for helping.